# Como selecionar elementos JSON com Python?

Tags: python, json

Estou usando uma API de notícias, ela me devolve um arquivo JSON:

```
import json
import requests

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&''apiKey=be7b904493554491afde83281651f05a')
response = requests.get(url)
noticias = json.loads(response.text)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu dou o `print` de `noticias` mas só com o primeiro título:

```
 print(noticias['articles'][0]['title'])
```

Como eu poderia fazer para trazer pelo menos os 10 primeiros títulos?

Comment: O zero ali que usou refere-se à posição na lista de artigos que está acessando. Se quer os 10 primeiros, basta variar esse valor de 0 a 9.

Comment: quando eu faço isso ele retorna erro

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Precisa fazer um laço de repetição e acessar cada um separadamente.

Answer (score 6):

Para manipular um JSON, fica mais fácil se antes você entender a sua [sintaxe/estrutura](http://json.org/) (<sup><sub>*e [não é tão difícil](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json)*</sub></sup>).

Basicamente, há duas estruturas que considero as mais importantes: arrays e objetos.

---

Um objeto JSON é um conjunto de pares "chave: valor", e é delimitado por `{}`. Por exemplo, se eu tenho:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "idade": 20
}
```

Este objeto possui a chave "nome", cujo valor é a string "Fulano", e a chave "idade", cujo valor é o número 20. Repare que em cada par "chave: valor" há um `:` separando-os, e cada par é separado por vírgulas.

---

Já um array JSON é uma lista de elementos, e é delimitado por `[]`. Por exemplo:

```
[ 10, "abc", 3 ]
```

Este array tem 3 elementos: o número 10, a string "abc" e o número 3 (todos separados por vírgulas).

---

O que pode tornar um JSON confuso é o fato de podermos ter estas estruturas aninhadas (podemos ter um objeto, com valores que são arrays, que por sua vez contém outros objetos, que podem ter outros objetos ou arrays, etc). Exemplo:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "idade": 20,
  "filmes_preferidos": [ "Clube da Luta", "Matrix" ]
}
```

Repare que agora o objeto possui a chave "filmes_preferidos", cujo valor é um array (pois está entre `[]`). Dentro deste array há 2 strings com os nomes dos filmes.

Mas nada impede que cada elemento do array seja também um objeto:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "idade": 20,
  "filmes_preferidos": [
    {
      "nome": "Clube da Luta",
      "ano_lancamento": 1999
    },
    {
      "nome": "Matrix",
      "ano_lancamento": 1999
    }
  ]
}
```

Repare que agora o array possui 2 objetos dentro dele: cada elemento do array está delimitado por `{}`, e cada um possui 2 chaves ("nome" e "ano_lancamento"). Repare também na vírgula após o `}` do primeiro filme, para separar os elementos do array.

E poderíamos ir além: dentro de cada objeto que representa um filme, uma das chaves poderia ter como valor outro array ou objeto, e dentro destes poderia ter outros arrays/objetos e assim por diante, e a estrutura pode ficar bem complexa.

Enfim, para ler e manipular um JSON, o ideal é primeiro olhar para a sua estrutura e ver onde estão as informações que você precisa: elas estão em um objeto? Em qual chave? O valor da chave é um array? Quais posições do array eu preciso? Os elementos do array são outros objetos ou arrays? E assim por diante...

---

No caso do seu JSON (eliminei algumas partes para simplificar):

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "totalResults": 38,
 "articles": [
  {
   "source": {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Yahoo.com"
   },
   "author": null,
   "title": "U.S. Futures Climb on Rate-Cut Bets; Dollar Drops: Markets Wrap - Yahoo Finance",
   ...
  },
  {
   "source": {
    "id": "cnbc",
    "name": "CNBC"
   },
   "author": "Elizabeth Schulze",
   "title": "France approves digital tax on American tech giants, defying US trade threat - CNBC",
   ...
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

Ele é um objeto (está delimitado por `{}`), que possui várias chaves ("status", "totalResults", "articles").

O valor da chave "articles" é um array (está delimitado por `[]`). Este array, por sua vez, possui vários objetos dentro dele (repare que cada elemento do array está entre `{}` e eles são separados por vírgulas). E cada um desses objetos possui as chaves "source", "author", "title", etc. Abaixo uma explicação mais detalhada:

```
 "articles": [   <-- chave "articles", seu valor é um array (este [ marca o início do array)
  {   <-- primeiro elemento do array é um objeto (este { marca o início do objeto)
   "source": {  <-- chave "source" do primeiro elemento do array, valor é outro objeto (pois está entre {})
    "id": null,
    "name": "Yahoo.com"
   },
   "author": null,  <-- chave "author" do primeiro elemento do array
   // chave "title" do primeiro elemento do array
   "title": "U.S. Futures Climb on Rate-Cut Bets; Dollar Drops: Markets Wrap - Yahoo Finance",
   ...
  },  <-- fim do primeiro elemento do array (este } marca o fim do objeto, a vírgula separa os elementos do array)
  {  <-- segundo elemento do array é um objeto (este { marca o início do objeto)
   "source": {  <-- chave "source" do segundo elemento do array, valor é outro objeto (pois está entre {})
    "id": "cnbc",
    "name": "CNBC"
   },
   "author": "Elizabeth Schulze",  <-- chave "author" do segundo elemento do array
   // chave "title" do segundo elemento do array
   "title": "France approves digital tax on American tech giants, defying US trade threat - CNBC",
  },  <-- fim do segundo elemento do array (este } marca o fim do objeto, a vírgula separa os elementos do array)
  ...  <-- aqui continua os demais elementos do array
 ]  <-- este ] fecha o array
```

Sabendo disso, agora precisamos saber como o Python transforma este JSON em estruturas da própria linguagem. Na documentação do módulo `json` temos [esta tabela](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json-to-py-table):

| JSON | Python |
| --- | --- |
| object | dict |
| array | list |
| string | str |
| number (int) | int |
| number (real) | float |
| true | True |
| false | False |
| null | None |

Ou seja, objetos são mapeados para dicionários, e arrays são mapeados para listas. Sendo assim, a sua variável `noticias` será um dicionário (já que o JSON em questão é um objeto). Por isso, ao acessar `noticias['articles']`, você obtém o valor da chave "articles", que no caso será uma lista.

Por isso `noticias['articles'][0]` retorna somente o primeiro elemento do array (listas começam do índice zero). E este valor, no caso, é outro dicionário, que refere-se ao objeto que é o primeiro elemento do array (e este dicionário, por sua vez, possui a chave "title").

---

Dito isso, se quer percorrer os títulos, basta percorrer a lista `noticias['articles']`. Para obter os 10 primeiros, use a [sintaxe de *slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295), e em seguida percorra os elementos usando um `for`:

```
for artigo in noticias['articles'][:10]:
    print(artigo['title'])
```

No caso, `[:10]` é uma forma de obter uma "sub-lista" contendo apenas os 10 primeiros elementos. Se quiser percorrer a lista toda, basta remover este trecho e usar `for artigo in noticias['articles']`.

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser todos os títulos:

```
for artigos in noticias.get('articles'):
        print(artigos['title'])
```

Se quiser apenas os 10 primeiros:

```
for artigos in noticias.get('articles')[:10]:
    print(artigos['title'])
```

Comment: deu certo! só fiquei na duvida do que seria o "_" que você colocou no for

Comment: @Filipe.C por convenção da comunidade, usa-se uma variável chamada `_` quando o valor dela não será interessante para o contexto. Não é o caso da resposta, então na minha opinião foi uma infelicidade fazer isso. Seria muito mais legível chamá-la de `article`

Comment: É bem isso que o @AndersonCarlosWoss. Usar `_` é uma mania minha quando vou acessar algo dentro de alguma coisa, e esta, como um todo, não me interessa futuramente (tratando-a como uma variável de 'descarte'). Concordo que não é a maneira mais legível. Vou editar a resposta.